# regex on html line between > and < character

Tags: html, regex

I have made a HTML Get request, I want to parse the result.

For example, I have a line :

```
<span class="lm3_eq1">Energetyk-BGU Res.<span class="hidden-xs"><img src="/image/logo/club/16/equipe-logodefaut.png" width="16" height="16" alt="Energetyk-BGU Res."></span></span><span class="lm3_score" id="score_3282826">0 - 1</span><span class="lm3_eq2"><span class="hidden-xs"><img src="/image/logo/club/16/equipe-logodefaut.png" width="16" height="16" alt="FK Ruh Brest Res."></span>FK Ruh Brest Res.</span>
```

I want to have the following result :

- Energetyk-BGU Res.
- 0 - 1
- FK Ruh Brest Res.

I'm not an expert with regex

I have tried this but this doesn't work :

```
(?<=>)(.*)(?=<)
```

The result is

```
"Energetyk-BGU Res.<span class="hidden-xs"><img src="/image/logo/club/16/equipe-logodefaut.png" width="16" height="16" alt="Energetyk-BGU Res."></span></span><span class="lm3_score" id="score_3282826">0 - 1</span><span class="lm3_eq2"><span class="hidden-xs"><img src="/image/logo/club/16/equipe-logodefaut.png" width="16" height="16" alt="FK Ruh Brest Res."></span>FK Ruh Brest Res."
```

Thanks

Comment: which language are you using? some languages don't support some regex function, that's why i am asking

Comment: [Parsing HTML with regex is a hard job](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4234491/372239)
HTML and regex are not good friends. Use a parser, it is simpler, faster and much more maintainable.

Comment: @Berto99 I develop in c++11

Comment: One way is to use a language that supports split. I've simulated a split with the two regex's below. If using C++11, do a regex replace as in my examples, then do another regex search using `[^\n]+` which will return all the non-tagged text.

Answer (score -2):

You have to use `(.*?)`. Look up lazy vs greedy quantifiers.